# minimizing variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. These are independent and we know that $E(X_1)=E(X_2)=\mu$. We also know that $\sigma^2_1$ and $\sigma^2_2$ are not necessarily the same.

we estimate $\mu$ by the weighted average $\bar{\mu}=wX_1+(1-w)X_2$.

How should $w$ be chosen in $[0,1]$ to minimize the variance of $\bar{\mu}$?

I started looking at this as

$$V(\bar{\mu})=E(\bar{\mu}^2)-E(\bar{\mu})^2$$

but I am not sure if this is right and if it is I am stuck. I am not sure how to take what we have and run it out. I know the final answer should be:

$$w=\frac{V(X_2)}{V(X_1)+V(X_2)}$$

Comment: $\sigma_i^2$ is presumably the variance of $X_i$?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is enough to say that independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$ implies that
$$ V(\bar{\mu})=w^2 V(X_1)+(1-w)^2 V(X_2) $$
and this value as a function of $w$ has a minimum either at $w=0$ or $w=1$, or at a point where its derivative ($\tfrac{d}{dw}$) has a zero (and its easy to see that this happens at $w=\tfrac {V(X_2)}{V(X_1)+V(X_2)}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking.  $\operatorname{Var}(\overline\mu) = w^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-w)^2\sigma_2^2$, which you can minimize the usual calculus way.